# How to change python's "full name" (something like `cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu`)?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-import, python-c-extension, python-install

I installed Python 3.5 from source and broke a number of modules on Python 3.4, which unfortunately, was an essential part of Ubuntu. I've been trying to fix the system, now I'm almost there, with (hopefully) the last problem: My Python 3.4 only recognize C modules with name `*.cpython-34m.so`, while all packages from Ubuntu repository are named `*.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. It seems that the `cpython-34m` stuff is the full name of Python, so I need to change it in accord with Ubuntu's expectation. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is installing two versions of Python in parallel out of question?

Comment: @Robus The two Python installations didn't overwrite each other's file. That's all I know.

Comment: Surely Python 3.5 has been installed `/usr/local/`? If so, remove 3.5 and check everything is working correctly

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I don't think Python can be easily removed, since Python's makefile has no `uninstall` target.

Comment: True, but you should be able to find the majority of the install by hand. E.g. remove `/usr/local/bin/python`, `/usr/local/lib/python` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying makes no sense.  The name cannot be changed, for a good reason.  The reason the names are different is to prevent incompatible versions from mixing up each other.  You can compile a different version with different options and then the name will be different, too.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of the package management is to satisfy all dependencies through the repositories. Theoretically there should be no need to install anything from the sources.

If you need a different Python version for some specifical reasons, virtual environments would be the thing to look for:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Python 3.4 via Ubuntu package system, and suddenly everything worked fine. I still have no clue how Ubuntu customize its own Python, since Python's `configure` command has no related option at all. Anyway, it works, so why bother :P. Finally, thank you for helping me with this problem.